# SQLite - update command yields null values

Tags: sqlite

I'm having trouble performing some update on a SQLite database. I'm using the SQLite 3 shell for Windows.
I'm running the following command:

```
update resovled_chrom_counts set genus =  
case resolved_name_full  
when resolved_name_full is not null and resolved_name_full != ''  
then substr(resolved_name_full,0,instr(resolved_name_full,' ')-1)  
else  
substr(original_name,0,instr(original_name,' ')-1)  
end;
```

It seems to work on most rows, but some  simply end up with a null value in their genus field. I tried checking some of them manually, by using the 'id' field of this table. For example, I found out that the row with id='kew-1' is null in it's genus field, and ran the following query:

```
select substr(resolved_name_full,0,instr(resolved_name_full,' ')-1)  
from resovled_chrom_counts  
where id='kew-1';
```

and to my surprise, I got a result (not null)!
Looks like the query works under the 'select' statement, but not under the 'update' statement.
Can anyone give an explanation and/or a solution?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are the actual values in the table?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but for the row I mentioned (with id='kew-1'), the value in the resolved_name_full field is 'Abelmoschus esculentus (L.) Moench', so when running the 'select' statement I get 'Abelmoschus', but when performing the update command, the genus field is set to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `substr(resolved_name_full...` but with the CASE.

A [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) can have two different forms:

1. `CASE x WHEN y THEN ...`: This compares the value of `x` against the value of `y`.
2. `CASE   WHEN a THEN ...`: This checks whether the value of `a` is true or false.

The problem in the UPDATE statement is that there is a value (`resolved_name_full`) directly after the CASE, so the value of `resolved_name_full` is compared with the value of the expression `resolved_name_full is not null and resolved_name_full != ''`, and this comparison always fails because `resolved_name_full` never happens to be `0` or `1`.

Just use the second form of the CASE expression:

```
update resovled_chrom_counts set genus =
case
when resolved_name_full is not null and resolved_name_full != ''
then substr(resolved_name_full,0,instr(resolved_name_full,' ')-1)
else
substr(original_name,0,instr(original_name,' ')-1)
end;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/086d9/2)</kbd>